# Update/remove page ESP8266 Webserver

Tags: arduino, webserver, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I'm using the [`ESP8266WebServer.h`](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266WebServer/src/ESP8266WebServer.h) library for the ESP8266. Files can be served to a specific filename by using something like:

```
...

void example() {
  sendFile(200, "text/html", data_example, sizeof(data_example));
}

...

webServer.on ("/example.html", example);
```

Once a file is served it *cannot* be updated by executing `server.on ("/example.html", example2);`.

**How can a hosted file be removed (or updated to a blank file) so that it will return a 404 error ?**

Comment: `if (some condition) serve_file(); else serve_404_error();`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not include a conditionnal logic in your example() function in order serve a 404 page when necessary ?

Hope it helps.